# Unclear wrong argument

Tags: list, error

The following expression:

```
(car input-method-function)
```

Give the following message:

```
Wrong type argument: listp, list
```

Why? input-method-function is list.

Comment: The value of `input-method-function` is the *symbol* `list`. A symbol is not a list: try evaluating `(symbolp input-method-function)` - it returns `t`; OTOH, evaluating `(listp input-method-function)` returns `nil`. IOW,  it is a *symbol*, not a *list* - and you cannot take the `car` of a symbol.

Comment: @NickD -- I beat you by 3+ minutes :) ... Please feel free to edit my answer to incorproate your comments and any additional information that may be helpful to the O.P. or future users.

Answer (score 2):

When describing the variable `input-method-function` with `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable`, the `*Help*` buffer contains the following preamble:

```
input-method-function is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is ‘list’

Documentation:
If non-nil, the function that implements the current input method.
```

Although the value is `list`, it is not actually a list - in the same way that if my name were `Martian`, that does not mean that I *am* a Martian.  Instead, it is the function named `list`.  As such, the symbol `list` cannot be treated as a list and `car` cannot be used in this situation.

Lisp provides predicates that can test whether something is a symbol or a list or a string or a number etc: `(symbolp input-method-function) ==> t` - this says that the value of `input-method-function` (i.e. `list`) is indeed a symbol. But `(listp input-method-function) ==> nil` - this says that the value of `input-method-function` (i.e. 'list') is *not* a list.

Comment: See what you think of the edit.

Comment: @NickD -- looks good -- thank you!